# Proof that all n-length subsets have been generated from a set.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

I have a function in a computer program that generates integer subsets within an integer set. The function takes an set of sequential numbers and finds all the possible subsets of a given length. The best way to describe it is with an image:

[image: set and subsets]

The output of a function call that takes an input of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} with a subset length of 3 gives an output of:

```
123
124
125
126
127
134
135
136
137
145
146
147
156
157
167
234
...
```

and so on until the last subset `567`

My question is, given the known input, subset length and output, is there a non-iterative mathematical way to prove the output is correct? By correct I mean all possible subsets have been fully and accurately generated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of possible sets in your example should be $\dbinom{7}3 = 35$. Hence, have functions which checks if there are $35$, $3$ element sets and any two such sets are pairwise distinct.

In general, if you have $n$ elements and you are looking for $k$ element subsets, the number of such subsets is $\dbinom{n}k = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the equation to test the set count, as you provided. As far as the check for sets being pairwise distinct that's trivial enough, just comparing subsets as the subset array is traversed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that all the outputs are distinct; this might be a consequence of generating them in increasing lexicographic order as appears to be the case here.  You need to know how many of them are generated.  If you generated $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of size $k$ from an input set of size $n$, then you generated all of them.